# Parse Get JSON Sub-Object Contents in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object, parse-platform

I'm trying to write a Parse query with the code

```
exports.getProfile = function(req, res) {
    var Profile = Parse.Object.extend("Profile");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Profile);
    query.equalTo("username", "philfishbein");
    query.find({
        success: function(object) {
            console.log(object);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("error!");
        }
    });
}
```

Which outputs among other things:

```
[ { _serverData: 
     { age: '17',
       email: 'phil@fishbe.in',
       facebook: 'philfishbein',
       fullname: 'Phil Fishbein',
       github: 'fishbein',
       languages: [Object],
       location: 'New Jersey',
       twitter: 'fishbein',
       username: 'philfishbein',
       years: '5' },
    ...} ]
```

However when I change the log statement to something like `object._serverData`, it returns `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON is an array of dictionaries.  In this case it has just one entry in the array.  Try `object[0]._serverData` instead.